# How to send variables from Node.js to Socket.io and display on local webpage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js, socket.io

I'm working on a project where my job is to use Node.js and Socket.io to read a text file (contain 3 real time readings) and got the data in 3 variables, then send them to Socket.io and get them displayed on the website continuously without having to refresh it. I ran my codes, it did not give any errors, but it did not display anything on the website either. So I don't know what is wrong in my code. I need help with passing variables from Node.js to Socket.io and get them displayed on the my web page. 
This is my server file:

```
var http = require('http').createServer(handler); //require http server, and cr$
var fs = require('fs'); //require filesystem module
var io = require('socket.io')(http) //require socket.io module and pass the htt$

http.listen(8080); //listen to port 8080
function handler (req, res) { //create server
  fs.readFile(__dirname + '/index.html', function(err, data) { //read file inde$
    if (err) {
      res.writeHead(404, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'}); //display 404 on error
      return res.end("404 Not Found");
    }
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'}); //write HTML
    res.write(data); //write data from index.html
    return res.end();
  });
}
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
   setInterval(function(){
   var array = fs.readFileSync('report.txt').toString().split("\n");
   var volt = (array[0]);
   var power = (array[1]);
   var temp = (array[2]);
   socket.emit('volt',{'volt': volt});
   socket.emit('power',{'power': power});
   socket.emit('temp',{'temp': temp});
   }, 1000);
});
```

index.html file :

```
<body>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.0.3/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
  var socket = io('http://10.117.230.219:8080');
  socket.on('volt', function (data) {
    $('#volt').text(data.volt);
  socket.on('power', function (data) {
    $('#power').text(data.power);
  socket.on('temp', function (data) {
    $('#temp').text(data.temp);
    });
</script>
   <div id="volt"></div>
   <div id="power"></div>
   <div id="temp"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing some tags on your HTML page including HTML and head.  You are also missing a closing `)}` for each `socket.on(...)` call in your script.  This is what it should look like:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.0.3/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.js"></script>
    <script>
        var socket = io('http://localhost:8080');
        socket.on('volt', function (data) {
            $('#volt').text(data.volt);
        })
        socket.on('power', function (data) {
            $('#power').text(data.power);
        })
        socket.on('temp', function (data) {
            $('#temp').text(data.temp);
        })
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="volt"></div>
    <div id="power"></div>
    <div id="temp"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

This should do it.

Comment: Good catch, thank you! I have changed it and there still nothing displayed on the web page :(

Comment: I have it running just fine.  I did change this line `var socket = io('http://localhost:8080');` to include point to the local machine.  You might want to check out the [Chrome Javascript Console](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/) to see if any errors are logged.  (As a test, you could also put a random string between the body tags to at least see if the page is loading.)

Comment: There were something wrong with my RPi IP address. I got it running now, thank you!

Comment: Great, glad it's working.  Please mark the answer correct if you believe it helped you out.  :)

Comment: I was trying to vote for your answer but it did not let me to be cause i'm too new, but i just marked your answer correct. Thanks again